# What git operation ports my changes from kernel 3.14.y to 3.15.y?

Tags: linux, git, merge, kernel, rebase

I am using the Linux kernel in an embedded project. When I started, I used git to clone from kernel.org what was then the current stable release, 3.14.2. As new 3.14 kernels were released, I was able to upgrade to them by using git rebase . For example, I upgraded to 3.14.10 by using

```
git checkout linux-3.14.y
git pull
git checkout myproject
git rebase v3.14.10
```

However, if I try to upgrade to the 3.15 series by using

```
git checkout linux-3.15.y
git pull
git checkout myproject
git rebase v3.15.3
```

or

```
git merge v3.15.3
```

I get git merge conflicts on files that I have never touched.

Is there a recommended way to upgrade from 3.14.10 to 3.15.3?

Comment: What is the states between `myproject` and `linux-3.15.y` before you do `git rebase`? (`git log --oneline --decorate --graph myproject linux-3.15.y` may help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is happening. Let's say the starting commit graph looks something like this:

```
                       -------------------------------------- myproject
                      /
                     /
         -----------/---------------------------------o------ linux-3.14.y
        /           C                             v3.14.10
       /                         B
  ----/---------------------------\-------------------------- master
      A                            \
                                    \
                                     --------------------o--- linux-3.15.y
                                                     v3.15.3
```

I don't know that it exactly looks like this, but it illustrates the issue.

When rebasing, git searches back in history for the first commit that is part of both the current branch and the "upstream" branch specified. It collects all these commits for the rebase operation.

When the "upstream" specified is the one from which the current branch was originally created, the collected commits include only my own commits on the current branch, so there are no conflicts.

When the "upstream" specified is not the one from which the current branch was originally created, which is the case for the "git rebase v3.15.3", the collected commits include ones that are not my own commits. In the example, the point of convergence is commit A, and the rebase operation would include everything from point A to myproject. The ones between point A and point C are probably inappropriate for the desired operation.

Instead, what is needed is to continue to use linux-3.14.y as the "upstream" branch for the purpose of identifying which commits to rebase, but to specify a separate commit onto which to rebase these commits. That is what the "--onto" switch is for. So the required operation to port myproject to the v3.15.y kernel is

```
git checkout myproject
git rebase linux-3.14.y --onto v3.15.3
```